# Embedding a youtube player without javascript

Tags: php

Donw really know if this is a stupid question or not but can you embed a youtube player inside a website without the use of javascript? I'm making an alternative version of a website for when javascript isnt enabled and dont really know if you can emmbed a youtube player using only php

Comment: **1.** Have a look at the embedding code that YouTube supply. Is there any javascript in it? **2.** Turn off javascript in your browser. Look at a page with an embedded YouTube video. Does it play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need javascript. You are only embedding an object/applet so it's all really just HTML+Flash.

See [the Youtube documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

use iFrames? use PHP and set a MIME type in combo with cURL?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed it normally using an iframe like so:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
```

...and it will either use HTML5 (where it can) or Flash otherwise.

I don't think it needs Javascript with either of those methods?

Comment: actually it seems that the iframe uses javascript to render the flash / video tags.

Comment: @user576875's observation is actually correct. The idea was to make an alternative to Youtube that does not rely on JS. If you simply embed the original with an iframe, you changed nothing at all. I have yet to find out why Youtube would need JS since I have it enabled all the time, but well... it's what OP has asked.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the observation is indeed correct. I'm as stumped as you as to why it's required though! In fairness though in this day and age I think it's pretty much guaranteed that the user will have Javascript turned on if they want to use most of the popular sites on the web...

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G50066Io-ow&list=PLF51D79F159020CC1"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/G50066Io-ow/hqdefault.jpg">Brian Eno - Sky Saw.wmv</a>
```

The only problem is that there is no arrow to remind the user they can click the image to watch a video.

Alas YouTube does not provide an "a*.jpg" version of images that could feature the arrow.